# Unsupported media type requested when requesting application/json on WCF Data Service

Tags: json, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am building a WCF data service (with .net 4.5 VS 2012) using Reflection Provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx) on my existing classes. I can successfully access the service with "Accept: application/atom+xml" in request header. however, I got an error "Unsupported media type requested" when changing "Accept" to "application/json" in request header. As I learned, WCF data service supports JSON, what should I do to enable querying json data on the service?

Thanks

Edit:
I paste my code below:
first I have the Product class defined:

```
[DataServiceKeyAttribute("Id")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I have my ProductContext class defined:

```
public class ProductContext
{
    private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    public ProductContext()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var product = new Product();
            product.Id = i;
            product.Name = "ID - " + i.ToString();
            product.Price = i + 100;
            products.Add(product);
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return products.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

and my ProductService.svc.cs

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class ProductsService : DataService<ProductContext>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Products", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        //config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe error "application/json"

Comment: Regfor, thanks for your quick reply, it's only a typo here (corrected) but not in my code.I tried many times in my code, and found only application/atom+xml supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using WCF Data Services 5.0, takes a look at this blog post which explains the changes in JSON support: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/11/what-happened-to-application-json-in-wcf-ds-5-0.aspx

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: add a request header of

MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a newer version of WCF Data Services you may need to use the following Accept header: `Accept: application/json;odata=verbose,text/plain`

This allows the plain text responses for scalar queries like `$count`, and also specifies the verbose version of JSON. I am using WCF Data Services 5.3 and this is what I found to be necessary. I have also seen `Accept: application/json;odata=light`, but I personally haven't needed that because the verbose version of odata is working fine.

Comment: Just be aware that the WCF Data Services client doesn't support the verbose JSON format, and in OData v4 (which is currently being standardized), that format is going away completely.

Comment: @JenS Thanks for the heads up. I just posted [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238497/how-would-an-upgrade-from-verbose-json-to-light-json-light-affect-someone-who-on) in case you know the answer.