# How would an upgrade from verbose JSON to JSON light affect someone who only looks at the data, and not the metadata?

Tags: json, wcf-data-services, odata

Can anyone explain to me concisely in plain English with a few bullet points what the main differences are between verbose JSON and JSON light for WCF Data Services? I found a document called "JSON light at a glance" by Microsoft, but it's 23 pages long! I don't care about metadata; I only care about the data. I know that JSON light drops the "d" wrapper. Anything else? Are the data types (dates, booleans, etc) sent in the same format?

EDIT: I realize that now Microsoft is now calling JSON light simply "JSON", and JSON verbose is the old, deprecated standard. I am calling the new standard "JSON light" for clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"I don't care about metadata; I only care about the data"

That's actually a great tagline for JSON Light as a whole :)

The core principle of JSON light is that servers can cut down on unnecessary metadata in the payload. When a client does need a certain bit of metadata (for example, the URL it should use to edit the entity), the client can generate that URI itself based on common OData URI conventions.

A client can control how much metadata the server should include in the payload by requesting one of the three different metadata levels:

- "application/json;odata=fullmetadata" for clients who need to use metadata and don't have a way to compute it themselves
- "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata" for clients who use metadata but are fine computing it themselves
- "application/json;odata=nometadata" for clients who don't care about any metadata whatsoever

If you're writing a client that really doesn't care about any metadata at all (where metadata includes edit links, entity types, property types, stream information, navigation properties, etc.), then you can request "application/json;odata=nometadata" and you'll just get back a bag of properties.

Even if you don't care about metadata, there are lots of little differences between JSON Verbose and JSON Light. I would strongly recommend relying on a library for this if you're in a language where one is available (for example, in .NET there's the WCF Data Services Client and in Javascript there's datajs or jaydata).  Here's a list of a couple differences off the top of my head:

- In OData v2, DateTimes could be represented using the ticks-based format (e.g., `"lastUpdated": "\/Date(1240718400000)\/"`), but in v3 JSON only ISO 8601 is supported (e.g., `"1992-01-01T00:00:00"`)
- There is no "d" wrapper on results payloads anymore.
- Instead of a "results" wrapper for collection results, there is now a "value" wrapper
- Instead of "__count" for inline count, JSON Light uses "odata.count"

As an example, take a look at the differences in the payload produced by this query:

http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=2&$format=application/json;odata=verbose

Versus this:

http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=2&$format=application/json;odata=nometadata

Comment: Thanks Jen. Excellent response. This information helped me realized that I was still referencing WCF Data Services 5.0 instead of the 5.3 that I had installed weeks ago. Doh! I went ahead and downloaded 5.5 and followed some of what I found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2012/04/16/upgrading-wcf-data-services-projects-to-wcf-data-services-5-0.aspx) to update. Now `application/json;odata=nometadata` works and I can get to work on making the minimal changes needed in the client code that handles the data. Thanks again.

Comment: is there a doc similar to http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/json-verbose-format/ anywhere for light format?

Comment: There wasn't really in OData v3, but in OData v4, the JSON format is what we called "JSON light" in v3, with some small modifications. You can find the v4 JSON documentation [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/odata-json-format-v4.0.html).

Comment: Does anyone know how to parse the count in JavaScript now that there is a dot in the object name? The browser literally sees "odata.count" as the object name, but when I use odata.count in code, it obviously tries to find the odata object, which does not exist. Thanks!

Comment: You can do `someJson["odata.count"]` to access the 'odata.count' property. But if you use a library like datajs, I don't think you need to do this by hand.